# Python parse url in string

Tags: python, regex, url

I'd like to get urls in strings.
For example I got:

```
"You got to see this link[http://some.link/you/have?to=see]"
```

I think theses are non-valid url characters: `"'()[]{}`

Comment: Can you please clarify more on your question and show us what you've tried until now?

Comment: They are valid URL characters. Is your strings all include URLs between square brackets [] or is it just an example?

Comment: @Selcuk This is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Your regex to find the URL would look something like this:

```
'https?://[^\"\'\(\)\[\]\{\}]+'
```

which is basically just looking for a string starting with 'http' or 'https' and then '://' and then all characters that follow that are not `"'()[]{}`

Comment: Not working with: `"You got to see this link[http://some.link/you/have?to=see]".split('https?://[^\"\'\(\)\[\]\{\}]+')` Maybe I've to use re.compile ?

Comment: try `re.findall('https?://[^\"\'\(\)\[\]\{\}]+', "You got to see this link[http://some.link/you/have?to=see]")[0]` this works for me, just tried it